# Editing elevation in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, elevation

I have a raster layer that covers a large area (three cities). When I load the raster layer into a 3D visualizer, there are multiple areas with a drastic change in the slope rather than a gentle smooth change in elevation.

Is there any way to smooth out the differences in the elevation or edit it ArcGIS?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213182/seamlessly-merging-usgs-dem-data-with-higher-resolution-survey/213231#213231

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your raster by converting it into TIN through the Raster To TIN Tool, then you can edit your TIN with the TIN Editing toolbar, after finishing and saving edits, convert your TIN into raster again through the TIN to Raster Tool.

You can use the Help for [The interactive TIN Editing toolbar](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tin/interactive-tin-editing-tools.htm) to learn about the TIN Editing Toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Mosaic to New Raster tool will help.

https://community.esri.com/thread/171826

OR

The elevation properties of a layer can be set on the Base Heights tab in ArcScene on the Layer Properties dialogue box. The different options available to define the elevation source are elevation derived from a surface, directly from the features, or as a constant offset to the layer.