# Artefacts when merging different resolution DEM

Tags: raster, gdal, dem, merge, gdal-merge

I am trying to merge a 10m DEM with a 30m DEM (10m DEM is a sub area of the 30m DEM). Both DEMs have the same projection and nodata value. I create a .vrt file:

```
gdalbuildvrt test.vrt *.tif -resolution highest -r cubicspline
```

That works fine, but at the border from high to low resolution, I get this artefacts:
[image]

Offset is not consistent:
[image]

10m data only doesn't produce any artefacts at the image border:
[image]

The first image shows hillshades I generated from the `test.vrt`. I couldn't find any solution to avoid getting this line at the transition between 10m and 30m data. The 10m data comes from an airborne laser, the 30m from satellite radar. So I guess only because of this different sources, the values are different and produce a gap.

Is there a possibility to tell GDAL to blend the datasets into each other (only at the outline of the 10m dataset)?

Comment: What is your data source? Where is the border between the two DEM?

Comment: The border between the two DEM is the line where the red arrow points to. The data source is 10m: https://kartkatalog.geonorge.no/metadata/dtm-10-terrengmodell-utm33/dddbb667-1303-4ac5-8640-7ec04c0e3918 and 30m: https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/astgtmv003/ I aligned the projection and the nodatavalue before merging both datasets.

Comment: Since your datasources used different CRS, they most likely had different reference points/level for elevation above sea level. You need to determine this difference and recalculate one of the two DEM.

Comment: Not 100% sure if that is what you mean. I think I did this when I warped the datasets. gdalwarp command for 30m: -s_srs "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +a=6378137 +b=298.257223563 +units=degree +no_defs" -t_srs "+proj=merc +ellps=sphere +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0.0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs +over" and for 10m: -s_srs "+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs" -t_srs "+proj=merc +ellps=sphere +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0.0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs +over"

Comment: Well, not the full command obviously, just the proj4 string of source and destination.

Comment: You need to determine, which reference sea level was used when creating each DEM. E.g. Germany and Switzerland have different references (one in the North Sea, the other somewhere in the Adriatic I guess) which differ by about 40 cm. Either check your data sources, or simply use the info-tool and check elevation values pre-merge on both sides of your merge-line after reprojection. This should give you a good estimation of the difference.

Comment: Well, the elevation values will be different anyway because the 30m values come from satellites, the 10m values from airborne laser. Is there any way how to blend, these two datasets into each other? Or maybe align the values at the merge-line with a smooth transition? I have found this example, but I don't have arcgis: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213182/seamlessly-merging-usgs-dem-data-with-higher-resolution-survey

Comment: Please try my suggestion, then come back with your findings. In my opinion this is the most likely errorsource.

Comment: Can you help me to clarify if I didn't do this already? When I reprojected the data I defined the source projection and source ellipsoid. Then reprojected both datasets into the same target SRS. See the two Proj4 strings above. Isn't that what you suggested?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amsterdam_Ordnance_Datum - this is what I am talking about.

Comment: I think I start to know what you mean. Have found a height reference model for the 10m dataset: https://kartkatalog.geonorge.no/metadata/hoeydereferansemodell-nn1954/9219f396-b9e9-47e7-a8de-d7ea03e29e5e Sorry haven't heard about this before, unfortunately I am no geographer. Will try to find out how to apply it.

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation =/ Basically you need to find out, how large the "difference" is between the two layers is and then use the raster calculator to modify one of the layers by e.g. substracting 25 cm from all elevation values in it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It is just that the offset isn't continuous at all. I added another picture to the post to show it. Sometimes the offset is there, sometimes not. Sometimes stronger, sometimes less.

Comment: Okay, idea... you could reproject and merge as you already did, but then add an additional step of reprojecting/reducing resolution, which might reduce the visibility of the artefacts.

Comment: Something else to consider: your source rasters may not be perfectly aligned ("snapped") with each other in X/Y, even though they are projected to the same CRS.  Check out the *Align Rasters* tool.

Comment: `gdalwarp` has a `-cblend` option to blend together datasets using a vector cutline, you could play with that